# How to handle complete project rewrite in git?

Tags: version-control, git

I'm developing a software library that I began during my PhD and used in my thesis. I've since started a research position and, as an experiment, I wanted to try rewriting parts to see if I could simplify it. This turned out to be way more successful than I expected. I rewrote years of work in a matter of weeks, and the end result is much cleaner than what I had before.

Now I want to make my rewrite public, but I'm not sure what to do about the revision history. I reference specific commits in the old version in my thesis, so I'd like to have those preserved for posterity (and so I can laugh at my junk code later.) I can think of 3 options:

1. Delete all the old code in one commit. Extract all the commits from the rewrite as patches and apply them one-by-one to the old repository.
2. Make a tag branch for the old code, say `my-lib-0.0.1`, explaining that it was a nascent version of the code from when I was young and foolish. Add the rewrite as a remote for the old code, then `git reset --hard rewrite/master`. This will replace the revision history of the old code with that of the rewrite.
3. Explain in the `README` for the old repo that it's deprecated, and keep the rewrite in an entirely new repo.

I don't like option 3, as I'd rather have everything in the same repository. Additionally, there is still a fair amount of shared code between the old and new versions. Option 2 has the virtue of keeping the revision history looking fairly clean (users won't have to clone 400+ commits of garbage from when I didn't know what I was doing) but keeping the history there in the unlikely event that someone does want to see it. On the other hand, I don't like the idea of "rewriting history", and to avoid cloning garbage commits I can always tell people to do shallow clones.

Which of these options is the least bad? Are there others that I haven't considered?

Comment: Two questions: (1) Is there any chance you will need to maintain the old version, e.g. someone important happened to be using it and would like some bug fixes, and doesn't want to upgrade to the new version?   and (2) If so, is there any chance you would want to be able to merge those changes into the new version at some point?

Comment: Are you the only committer?

Comment: @JohnWu I won't need to make bug fixes to the old version; it's alpha code anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm the only committer, so it's not as if burying the old code would be inconsiderate to any contributors.

Comment: Absent any other committers, it's unclear what value (if any) all that history would have for anyone else.

Comment: You can comunicate backwards compatibility using [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/).

Comment: If you want to rewrite your old library then just do it. Your PhD thesis will age like any other document: The world still turns and the thesis just documents the current state of the world. If the original code is still availa le and/or attached to the Thesis then you are fine

Answer (score 7):

This is a very typical situation in software development.

In my view, you should first tag the final version of your old code (no need to branch, as you can always branch from the tag if needed). Also, the rewriting takes place incrementally, and this means you commit changes gradually. When you reach your new version, you tag again and so on. In every release (tagging) you include a release notes document.

What you may come across, though, are code breaking changes. In this case, you communicate them by altering the version number and the release notes.